# Abs beginner Haskell pattern matching

Tags: haskell

I just managed to install Haskell and EclipseFP in the way that it all works under ubuntu! :)  It took me really long to make it all work with no --force :)
I starting explore learnyouahaskell and that pattern thing looks really fun... But I have question, for example I would like to calculate an equation like this:

```
equation :: [(Integer, Integer)]
equation = [ (x,y) | x <- [1..100],y<-[1..100], y == 2*x-4, x == 2*y-4]
```

I have to put limits on x and y ranges, but is it possible to use x<-[1..] and y<-[1..] and make the function stop after it finds first pair of x and y?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem with `x <- [1..], y <- [1..]` is that `x=2` will be tried only after all the possible pairs `(1,y)` have been tried, for each `y>=1`. However, if no such pair matches your criterion, trying all such pairs requires an infinite amount of time. In that case, we never get to `x=2` or any larger value for `x`.

What you need is a "fair" scheduler of all the pairs which does not get stuck on a strict subset of the cases. Mathematically, this is called a [dovetailing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dovetailing_%28computer_science%29) function. This is essentially a *bijective* function from naturals to pairs of naturals. Or, if you prefer, it is a way of enumerating all the possible pairs: here's such an enumeration

```
(1,1) (2,1) (1,2) (3,1) (2,2) (1,3) (4,1) (3,2) (2,3) (1,4) ...
```

The trick is to list all the pairs having sum 2, then those having sum 3, and so on. In Haskell those pairs can be coded as

```
-- pair components start from 1 as in the OP's code
allPairs :: [(Integer, Integer)]
allPairs = [ (x,y) | s <- [2..] , x <- [1..s] , let y = s - x ]
```

Indeed, this chooses the sum `s` first (infinitely many choices here), and then proceeds to lists the (finitely many) pairs having that sum.

Once you have done this, your code simply becomes:

```
equation :: [(Integer, Integer)]
equation = [ (x,y) | (x,y) <- allPairs, y == 2*x-4, x == 2*y-4]
```

And, if you just want the first element

```
firstSolution :: Integer
firstSolution = head equation
```

That's it!

(Keep in mind that evaluating `firstSolution` may not terminate if no solution exists.)

Answer (score 1):

We're looking at two equations here:

```
y = 2*x-4
x = 2*y-4
```

Substituting the first equation into the second,

```
x = 2*(2*x-4)-4
```

Expanding,

```
x = 4*x-12
```

So `x = 4`.

Substituting back in to the first equation, `y = 4`.

Thus the first and only solution is `x = y = 4`. You can solve this most simply in Haskell by defining

```
firstSolution = (4,4)
```

You can (and should) then write a HUnit test for the solution, to check that it really is a solution, and a QuickCheck property for the solution to check that it is the first one.

Comment: Well, I am not sure if it is a serious answer. I think the OP expects to understand how the equation can be solved with Haskell.

Comment: @thefourtheye, I recognize that. I'm trying to demonstrate that one aspect of the Haskell way is to try to understand and simplify the problem as much as possible before writing any code.